# Is there a cross-browser library for face and eye recognition?

Tags: javascript, flash, webrtc, face-recognition

Does someone know of a cross-browser webcam library for face and eye recognition?

There are many WebRTC and HTML5 `getUserMedia` libs, but they are not working in Safari, which is the main browser in my project.

Comment: [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/), [jsFeat](http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/), [HAAR.js](https://github.com/HAAR.js), [FILTER.js](https://github.com/FILTER.js) (author of last two libs)

Comment: I know all this libs - they are not working on Safari

Comment: what is the exact problem you have in safari, can you post an example code?

Comment: is the safari problem a problem with image recognition libs or with getUserMedia access?

Comment: Safari doesn't support webrtc and getusermedia

Comment: then i suggest change the question to address that and any workarounds (e.g flash fallback or java)